# How do I create a CompletionField with multiple inputs that have different weights?

Tags: elasticsearch, autocomplete

For a single Input suggestion list the following code works:

```
     var completionField = new CompletionField

     {
         Input = completionList,
         Weight = weight

     };

     this.Suggest = completionField;
```

But I would like to have multiple lists of suggestions with different weights and be able to search a single completion field. I'm not sure how to accomplish that in Nest.

I do see that it is supported though:

```
PUT music/song/1?refresh
{
    "suggest" : [
        {
            "input": "Nevermind",
            "weight" : 10
        },
        {
            "input": "Nirvana",
            "weight" : 3
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define your completion field like this:

```
[Completion]
public List<CompletionField> Suggest { get; set; }
```

And provide a list of completion fields (with different weights if desired) you'll end up with the following in your index.

```
"suggest": [
  {
    "input": [
      "higherweightedterm"
    ],
    "weight": 1000
  },
  {
    "input": [
      "lowerweightedterm"
    ],
    "weight": 100
  }
]
```